# Adding Custom Layout and Views to Preference Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I searched a lot but i was not able to find nothing clear. Now I have a preference fragment that use a preference hierarchy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/preferencefrag_default_folder">


    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="images_preference"
        android:title="@string/title_images_preference"
        android:dialogMessage="@string/folder_should_settings"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/title_images_preference"
         />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="music_preference"
        android:title="@string/title_music_preference"
        android:dialogMessage="@string/folder_should_settings"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/title_music_preference"
        />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="downloads_preference"
        android:title="@string/title_downloads_preference"
        android:dialogMessage="@string/folder_should_settings"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/title_downloads_preference"
        />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="About the author">

</PreferenceCategory>
```

I'd like to add, below "About the author", a CardView, but I wasn't able to find how to do it (I suppose I need to add a custom layout).

Comment: Hope you get an answer - I'm also looking for an answer to this sort of question.